# How do I completely reset a SharePoint instance back to its factory settings?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I installed SharePoint on my local machine, and tried to restore a backup to it (to create a dev environment).  The restore completely hosed the site, and now I can't get it to come up.  So, I want to completely restore the entire site back to the way it is when you first install SharePoint Foundation 2010.  I can't find a "reset to factory settings" option.  Please help!

Comment: What do you call a site here? CA site itself?

Comment: Like, the WHOOOOOOOOLE thing.  http : // myserver/.  The whole shebang.

Comment: what type of restore you did, site backup / restore or farm backup and restore?

Comment: I took a .bak that was created in central admin on the production server.  Copied it locally, then ran the "Restore-SPSite -Identity <site> -Path <somepath/something.bak> -Force" command in powershell

Comment: When I ran that command, PowerShell just sat there for about 5 hours.  I left it overnight, and when I came back, my machine had been restarted.  I tried to navigate to the site, and got an error.

Comment: ok, now if you edit your questions and add the production and dev farm versions/build number and error you are getting...that will be great...

Comment: Restore-SPSite doesn't have any effect on anything but one site. Why not just use CA to delete corrupt site or maybe webapp?

Comment: Well, that's kinda what I'm asking.  CA is Central Admin, right?  I don't see an option to delete or create sites.

Comment: on central admin > application management > Under site collection...you will all options from create new site to delete a site collection etc

Comment: Or use Remove-SPSite -Identity <site>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is no way to reset a site in the way you are referring to if you don't have a backup of your previous site. I would start by identifying where the problem is and trying to solve it. If it's a master page that is playing tricks - you can try to revert back to default master page. If it's a page - try resetting it to Site Definition. The Reset to Site Definition command is not available for every page in a site. If the page was not created by customizing an existing page, but instead was either created from a blank page or created in another program and then imported into the site, then the page has no association with the site definition, and therefore you cannot reset it to the site definition.

If that doesn't help and you don't want to troubleshoot the issues, your only option is to delete the site and create a new one.

Could you please provide more detail what exactly is not working?

Comment: Yeah, let's delete the site and create a new one lol.  That sounds pretty much like what I'm trying to accomplish anyways.  How does one do that?  I can't believe Central Admin doesn't have a "reset the site to the way it was when you installed SharePoint option."  Essentially, I'm trying to create a copy of my production environment.  So, I'm not too interested in salvaging the site that is now corrupted... I just wanna start fresh and retry the backup.

Comment: I just uninstalled SharePoint Foundation and reinstalled it.  It created a blank site, and I immediately took a backup.  So, at least now I have a vanilla backup that I can now restore if things foul up again.

Comment: next time create a new site. you didnt need uninstall and reinstall all of SP.  Depending on what you have...you may have lost custom content types, master pages and more...

Comment: Yep, the only thing you had to do is delete the site from Central Administration. You should start with SharePoint documentation on MSDN. And update your question with the EXACT error you're getting. "Site is messed up" or "oh noes, site is RUINED" won't be of much help. Please be specific.